# why cscope does not show complete result list?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, cscope

[image]

I run a cscope command `cs f s free` and get one of the 21 results but I can not see the whole results list, how to fix it?

Comment: Well, some cscope commands show a list and other don't so… what command did you run?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issues while running :cs (vim cscope) commands from vim. The entire cscope list is actually in quickfix window.

To see the equickfix window (containing list), **run *:cope* or *:cw* command** inside from vim.

Answer (score 0):

Remove option in cscopequickfix

```
:set cscopequickfix=
```

or comment the line in .vimrc containing cscopequickfix